# Transferring ArrayList to Global ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have created Global Variables that are required at different steps in the entire Application Cycle. Below is the GlobalVariable.java created:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalVariable extends Application {
    private String globalVariableOne;

    public String getGlobalVariableOne() {
        return globalVariableOne;
    }

    public void setGlobalVariableOne(String globalVariableOne) {
        this.globalVariableOne = globalVariableOne;
    }
}
```

Then I am easily able to Get and Set this Global Variable from any activity using the below code.

```
final GlobalVariable globalVariable = (GlobalVariable) getApplicationContext();

//To Set the globalVariableOne Value in an Activity
globalVariable.setGlobalVariableOne("My Value");

//To Get the globalVariableOne Value in a
String readGlobalVariableOne = globalVariable.getGlobalVariableOne();
```

Now I have an ArrayList `localArrayList` created by using the below code in my Activity.

```
List<String> localArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

int maxLength = "10";

for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    String valueOne = "Value "+i;
    String valueTwo = "Value "+i;

    localArrayList.add(valueOne));
    localArrayList.add(valueTwo);
}
```

I want this ArrayList to be stored as a Global ArrayList accessible and editable by any Activity within my Application. I am not sure how to do it.

Can anyone help me in editing my GlobalVariable.java to define the Global ArrayList and guide me on how to Get and Set this Global ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should become like this:

```
public class GlobalVariable extends Application {
    private String globalVariableOne;
    private List<String> globalArrayList;

    public String getGlobalVariableOne() {
        return globalVariableOne;
    }

    public void setGlobalVariableOne(String globalVariableOne) {
        this.globalVariableOne = globalVariableOne;
    }

    public List<String> getGlobalArrayList() {
        return globalArrayList;
    }

    public void setGlobalArrayList(List<String> globalArrayList) {
        this.globalArrayList = globalArrayList;
    }
}
```

Then in you code you can do:

```
GlobalVariable myAppClass = (GlobalVariable)getApplicationContext();
//saving the list
myAppClass.setGlobalArrayList(/*put here the list to save*/);
//getting the list
List<String> globalArrayList = myAppClass.getGlobalArrayList();
```

But i really don't like this approach of putting every global variable inside the custom Application class...

Comment: What do you recommend? Please guide.

Comment: How to Get and Set based on this solution? This is something Android Studio is automatically generating for me. But I am not sure how to transfer my localArrayList to this Global ArrayList.

Comment: i've updated my answer, BTW you should use Databases, Shared Preferences, Files, Bundles (to move small data between activities) etc.. etc.. to save data for use in every part of the app.